# How to find who is li's parent?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say we have this list:

```
<ul title="Fruit">
<li onClick="func(this)">Apple</li>
<li onClick="func(this)">Banana</li>
</ul>
<ul title="Meat">
<li onClick="func(this)">Chiken</li>
<li onClick="func(this)">Duck</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to find from which **ul** the **li** is clicked?

Comment: Yes. Not that you have to but you should check out jQuery since it's great at this stuff.

Comment: `this.value` will be undefined.

Comment: @xdazz yes you right I changed it yo "this"

Comment: @keyser—you don't need a 4,000 line library to read a standard element property.

Comment: @RobG That's very true, but that's not what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `parentNode`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function func(el) {
      alert(el.parentNode.title);    
    }
</script>

<ul title="Fruit">
<li onClick="func(this)">Apple</li>
<li onClick="func(this)">Banana</li>
</ul>
<ul title="Meat">
<li onClick="func(this)">Chiken</li>
<li onClick="func(this)">Duck</li>
</ul>​​​​​
```

Also note that `value` is only used for **`form`** elements such as `input` and `select`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JwELQ/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You should just pass `this` to the function, and use `.parentNode` to get its parent.

```
function func(element) {
  var parent = element.parentNode;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(this.parentNode.title === "Fruit") {
 // first one
}
else {
   // the other ul
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`obj.parentNode` or using jQuery just: `$(obj).parent()`

Comment: The "just" option from jQuery requires more characters, so perhaps "just `.parentNode` is more apt.